# failing to update grid-template-areas css property via java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can see the property **grid-template-areas** inside the style object:

```
document.getElementById("elem-id").style
```

i tried setting it via :

js directly

```
document.getElementById("elem-id").style.gridTemplateAreas = "a a b"
```

jquery

```
$("#elem-id").css({"grid-template-areas":"a b c"})
```

but nothing seems to work, the property remains empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting Template Areas like that will require nested quotes. It needs one set of quotes for the overall JavaScript string, and within that, it needs a pair of quotes to denote each set of row cells in the styling.

The actual column and row declarations have not been provided. But anyway one of the following should work, depending on whether you have declared a single row of 3 cells, or 3 rows of 1 cell each:

```
document.getElementById("elem-id").style.gridTemplateAreas = "'a a b'";
```

Or:

```
document.getElementById("elem-id").style.gridTemplateAreas = "'a' 'a' 'b'";
```

Comment: works great ! i only needed a single row, weird no error message is prompt when invalid format is given